# How do I test convergence of this series $1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac{2^2}{3^3}+\frac{3^3}{4^4}+\dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**An infinite positive term series** is given :
$$1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{2^2}{3^3}+\frac{3^3}{4^4}+....$$

and I have to test its convergence.

I am having trouble in finding out it's $n^{th}$ term.
I Initially thought about something like $$U_n=\frac{(n-1)^{(n-1)}}{n^n} \text{ for n>1}$$
But my book suggested 
$$U_n=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)\times n +1}$$

Funny thing is, it fails miserably to get the required series.

Can someone suggest a better $n^{th}$ term? And how to proceed further from it.

Thank You!

Comment: It's $$U_n=\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$

Comment: @Fakemistake sorry. edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
U_n=\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}=\frac1n\cdot\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}.
$$
A limit familiar from the definition of Napier's constant then leads to a lower bound proving that the series diverges.

Comment: Thank you. I used the hint and used Limit form of comparison test

Comment: That will work nicely,  @TheDeadLegend :-)

Comment: It was a loooong time I did not see somebody telling about *Napier's constant*. This was how I learnt it. More beautiful than the trivial shorcut *e*.